# Why no 'SparkSession' below my 'org.apache.spark.sql'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I use IDEA and SBT to create a project in my MAC. When I want to use SparkSession, I can only find `catalyst` below `spark.sql`.

I try different version about Scala and spark, but it doesn't work.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object App {
    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        val spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("GitHub push counter")
            .master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate()

        val sc = spark.SparkContext()
    }
}
```

the first line `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` is red in IDEA.

Below is the `build.sbt` in the project:

```sh
name := "SparkExample"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.2"
```

I don't configure Hadoop, cause I only want to run it locally and do some exercise. I hope you can help me.

Comment: You need also `spark-sql` dependency for SparkSession as `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.2"`

Comment: He's using SBT though.  It's the same issue but you can't expect people to discern huge differences like that.  Sometimes you just need to see an example

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a rookie in that field, and I never use SBT and Maven before. But now I think I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add spark-sql as well

```
val sparkVersion = "2.4.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
)
```